# HttpAttributeListener not working?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I am trying to implement a HttpAttributeListener in my web-app. I tried everything and looked through my code a dozen of times but it is not working. The sysout in MyAttribute should execute but it is not. Something is wrong in my code and I dont see it. Please help.

Here is my HttpAttributeListenerClass:

```
public class MyAttribute implements HttpSessionAttributeListener{

@Override
public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    String attributeName = event.getName();
    Object attributeValue = event.getValue();
    System.out.println("##########################################");
    System.out.println("Attribute added : " + attributeName + " : " + attributeValue);
    System.out.println("##########################################");
}

@Override
public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    String attributeName = event.getName();
    Object attributeValue = event.getValue();
    System.out.println("##########################################");
    System.out.println("Attribute removed : " + attributeName + " : " + attributeValue);
    System.out.println("##########################################");
}

@Override
public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    String attributeName = event.getName();
    Object attributeValue = event.getValue();
    System.out.println("##########################################");
    System.out.println("Attribute replaced : " + attributeName + " : "           + attributeValue); 
    System.out.println("##########################################");
  }
 }
```

Here is my servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/ServletProjekt")
public class ServletProjekt extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   // request.getServletContext().log("Added a new request-log//abdi.");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("test", "test");
  }
```

And here is my web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
    Test.HttpSessionListenerTest
</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: What is `Test.HttpSessionListenerTest`? And what is its relation to `MyAttribute`?

Answer (score 0):

The listener class mentioned in web.xml is not correct,i suppose.It should be `MyAttribute` instead of `HttpSessionListenerTest`.

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
    MyAttribute //provide full package name like (com.XXX.MyAttribute)
</listener-class>
</listener>
```